# Import GeoJson to GoogleMap

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps, openstreetmap, geojson

I read answers, documentations here and there But I think I need more guidance when It comes to polygons. Here's what I need to do,

- Import city boundaries from GeoJson file
- Draw the polygon boundaries on my map using its coordinates

Link to the GeoJson file - https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?osmtype=R&osmid=3705576&class=boundary&addressdetails=1&hierarchy=0&group_hierarchy=1&polygon_geojson=1&format=json

As in the below code I tried `map.data.loadGeoJson()`
here's the Uncaught error , `message: "not a Feature or FeatureCollection" name: "InvalidValueError"`

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      //Maps
      center: { lat: 45.508, lng: -73.587 },
      markers: [],
      map:null,
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    this.initMap();
  },

  methods: {
        
    initMap() {
      // Create the map.
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: { lat: 37.910076, lng: -122.065186 },
      });
      //Set boundaries*********************************Where I'm stucked********************************    

     this.map.data.loadGeoJson(
    "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?osmtype=R&osmid=3705576&class=boundary&addressdetails=1&hierarchy=0&group_hierarchy=1&polygon_geojson=1&format=json"
     );

      
    },

    
}
```

Comment: Maybe compare [this](https://geojson.org/) with what you get from OSM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `type` in the return data needs to be "Feature" (currently it is "administrative").

Loading the data, modifying it, then loading the modified JSON into the DataLayer works for me:

```
  // request data
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?osmtype=R&osmid=3705576&class=boundary&addressdetails=1&hierarchy=0&group_hierarchy=1&polygon_geojson=1&format=json",
  }).done(function(data) {
    // modify the type to that expected by the DataLayer
    data.type = "Feature";
    map.data.addGeoJson(data);
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9ogat261/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: -28,
      lng: 137
    },
  });
  // zoom to show all the features
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  map.data.addListener('addfeature', function(e) {
    processPoints(e.feature.getGeometry(), bounds.extend, bounds);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?osmtype=R&osmid=3705576&class=boundary&addressdetails=1&hierarchy=0&group_hierarchy=1&polygon_geojson=1&format=json",
  }).done(function(data) {
    data.type = "Feature";
    map.data.addGeoJson(data);
  });

}

function processPoints(geometry, callback, thisArg) {
  if (geometry instanceof google.maps.LatLng) {
    callback.call(thisArg, geometry);
  } else if (geometry instanceof google.maps.Data.Point) {
    callback.call(thisArg, geometry.get());
  } else {
    geometry.getArray().forEach(function(g) {
      processPoints(g, callback, thisArg);
    });
  }
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Data Layer: Simple</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" async></script>
</body>

</html>
```